# How get to the attributes of a clicked image in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I know this seems easy, but I'm struggling to get the value of my source attribute when an image is clicked. I am getting this error when I click on any of the images:

> $ is not a function

I think it might have something to do with the context of the jQuery object. Any ideas would be grand.

```js
$(function () {
        ListData()
        .then(function(data){
            var imageHtml = [];
            //data is an array or image url's
            data.map(function(items, index){
                imageHtml.push('<img class="img-circle" id="user'+items['UserId']+'" src="'+items['PictureUrl']+ '"/>');                
            });

           var imagesString = imageHtml.join().replace(/,/g,"");
           
           //load images onto the page
           $('#gallery').append(imagesString);        
          // grab Jquery Object of all the images loaded to th epage with class img-circle       
           var Allimages = $(".img-circle");          
           Allimages.on('click',function(){
               var imageUrl= $(this).attr('id')
               
               })      
        
        })
              
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery">

</div>
```

Comment: ensure jquery is being loaded before this is being run.

Comment: I don't see how that error can be triggered by the click event itself.  If `$` is never defined then the click event will never be attached to the element, you'd be getting that error on the initial load of the page instead.  Also note that your code is missing a semi-colon, is this just the result of that typo?

Comment: Seems to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/zgay1wfc/

Comment: I removed the script tags from the stack snippet (they are not needed for that tool but are likely still needed for your site), and I included jQuery.  After doing that, it seems to work just fine.  Please check how and where you're loading jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine here on SO (see example below).

On your page, make sure that you're loading jQuery *before* running the code. You can do this by loading jQuery in your `<head>` and putting your code at the bottom of the body, or by wrapping your code in `$(document).ready()`, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code
});
```

Your code (works fine here):

```js
$(function(){

 var Allimages = $(".img-circle");
           Allimages.click(function(){
               var imageUrl= $(this).attr('src')
               console.log(imageUrl);               
           })           
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery">
<img class="img-circle" src="url1" style="top: 305px; left: 56px;"/>
<img class="img-circle" src="url2" style="top: 152px; left: 81px;"/>
<img class="img-circle" src="url3" style="top: 331px; left: 569px;"/>
<img class="img-circle" src="url4" style="top: 173px; left: 343px;"/>
<img class="img-circle" src="url5" style="top: 453px; left: 420px;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks freginold, that seems to partially work which i believe is because, on those occasions that it did, jquery may have loaded fully. So i updated the script to explain what i'm facing better. So the images are generated dynamically. it is only when i append them to the page that i get the jQuery object. Do you think this should make any difference? I have moved the Jquery script as you suggested. but the result is abit flaky.

Comment: @GottiJay It looks like you have one too many `})` in your code... not sure if that is a typo here or from your original code. When you say it's "flaky," do you mean sometimes it works and sometimes it gives you the `$ is not a function` error?

Comment: yes that's exactly what i mean by flaky...sorry for the typo

Comment: Just so I'm understanding correctly: You call the jQuery script on page load, and load the images dynamically. Then, sometimes clicking on the image shows its ID, and sometimes it gives the jQuery error?

Comment: That's a weird one. If the code breaks when it sees the `$` then that means the click handler is getting applied and called, but jQuery isn't being recognized for some reason. Do you have any code that would conflict with jQuery for the use of the `$` symbol?

Comment: The only thing i can think of is SharePoint(which is the platform i'm running the code on) which relies heavily on JavaScript.

Comment: It *could* be a SharePoint issue. Have you tried running your code using `jQuery` instead of `$` just to see if there's any difference?

Comment: Awesome man, that did it..thank you so much for your help and patience. Very much appreciated